# MySQL Service Not Starting

Tags: mysql, windows-2000

I installed MySQL 5.1.65 on Windows 2000 Server and it got properly installed for the first time. After some time I uninstalled it, deleted all the installation files and then wasn't able to finish the installation. It didn't give me any error, just the installer would stop responding while starting MySQL service. I tried at least 5 times but no luck.

I also tried selecting different service name while installing, but that too didn't help. ANy idea how can I get this sorted out ?

Comment: You should check for the log files. They are usually in the data directory. You should have a file named "<name of your server>.err"

Comment: [See here](http://www.windowsvalley.com/uninstall-mysql-from-windows/)it could help you

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back, if your installing the complete package install the minimum features, and this should work. Theirs a bug in MySQL that doesn't allow it to reinstalled on certain machines and versions of windows without reinstalling the OS.